# Grails/GORM simple many-to-many join query not working?

Tags: grails, join, many-to-many, grails-orm

OK, I'm new to Grails, as well as Hibernate.  I'm prototying something simple, and am stuck on querying the simplest many-to-many relationship via a join.

My model objects are:

```
class User {

    static hasMany = [roles:Role]

    String firstName
    String lastName
    String username
    String password

    // ... constraints and hooks omitted ...

}


class Role {
    static hasMany = [users:User]
    static belongsTo = User

    String name;
    // ... constraints and hooks omitted ...

}
```

After loading some data, I can see:

```
groovy:000> User.list().each { user-> println "$user.username :  ${user.roles.collect {it.name}}"}
smendola :  [Admin, Reviewer]
jripper :  []
jbauer :  []

groovy:000> Role.list().each { role-> println "$role.name: ${role.users?.collect {it.username}}"}
Admin: [smendola]
Guest: null
Reviewer: [smendola]
```

So, user smendola has two roles; other users have no roles; and the relationship is working from both directions.  Good.

Now the question:
I want to query for user with some role.  Of course I could use the return value from either of the above two queries and search it in Groovy, but I want the db to do this work.

I have futzed for HOURS trying to to construct a query that will give me the desired result, to no avail.  I believe I have followed online examples to a tee, and yet I cannot get this query to work.

One version of the query I've tried:

```
groovy:000> User.where { roles.name == 'Admin' }.list()
===> []
```

Or this variant:

```
groovy:000> User.where { roles {name == 'Admin'}}.list()
===> []
```

I've tried many, many other variations, including using .id, or role=someRoleInstance, etc. Nothing works.  I'm out of ideas.  Any help out there?

The database is h2, by the way.
Grails version 2.0.0

Thanks!

ADDED:
Two variants that were suggested, but also did not work:

```
groovy:000> User.createCriteria().list{ roles { eq('name', 'Admin') } }
===> []
groovy:000>
groovy:000> roleName = 'Admin'
===> Admin
groovy:000> def users = User.withCriteria {
groovy:001>   roles {
groovy:002>     eq('name', roleName)
groovy:003>   }
groovy:004> }
===> []
groovy:000>
```

Comment: I see the same behavior as you running `grails shell` but your examples and the criteria examples in the answers all work fine when running `grails console`. So I assume it's a shell issue. It's not as well maintained since the Swing-based console is so much easier to use.

Comment: You have GOT to be kidding me! I find it hard to believe that the shell could affect how ORM behaves, and yet, there it is.

Burt, please add your comment as an answer, so I can accept it (well, I accept what you said, not sure I accept that that's how Grails is!)  Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

```
User.createCriteria().list{
    roles{
        eq('name', 'Admin')
    }
}
```

Try using criteria

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you're willing to use a criteria query instead:

```
String roleName = 'Admin'

def users = User.withCriteria {
  roles {
    eq('name', roleName)
  }
}
```